# django - can't display images at admin

Tags: python, django

I have the following problem:

When I'm trying to upload an image at the admin panel [Fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eylhb.png) and then try to see it I get this error [Fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLenS.png)

Settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

portfolio/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField, URLField
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageField


class Project(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=100)
    description = CharField(max_length=250)
    image = ImageField(upload_to="portfolio/images")
    url = URLField(blank=True)
```

portfolio/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Project

admin.site.register(Project)
```

my_app/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Thanks :) and sorry for my cool english

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line so django can server media files during development.
`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
# all url conf
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```